# saving value to xml file - error occuring

Tags: c#, xml

I am receiving `"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."` error when I try and save the value to an XML file. I have tried messing around with it for a while now. I know it works cause I use the same code (with slight difference) to save the other values to this file. This is the only one not working.

```
public void SAVEtxtDestination(string txtFileStuff)
{
    XmlDocument myXmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
    myXmlDocument.Load("C:\\Users\\fthompson11\\WebFile.xml");


    XmlNode root = myXmlDocument.DocumentElement;
    var targetKey = "Path";
    XmlNode node = root.SelectSingleNode(string.Format("Text[@Key = '{0}']", targetKey));
    node.Attributes["Value"].Value = txtFileStuff;
    myXmlDocument.Save("C:\\Users\\fthompson11\\WebFile.xml");
}
```

Here is what my XML file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--This is to write the connection strings, text file location, and report destination.-->
<AdminPaths>
  <AdminPath Name="sqlConnection1" connectionString="tacohell" />
  <TextPath>
    <Text Key="Path" Value="Test3" />
    <Text Key="Report" Value="Test2" />
  </TextPath>
</AdminPaths>
```

Comment: If you debug your application where does the error points to, which line?

Comment: I suspect the path you're passing to SelectSingleNode isn't finding the element. Try "//Text[@Key = '{0}']" to make it find the Text node anywhere in the document.

Comment: points to node.attributs["value"].Value = txtFileStuff;

Answer (score 0):

In your comment you say indicate a lower case 'v' in value `nodes.attributes["value"].Value` in the example it's upper upper case.  Linq to XML is case sensitive, make sure the attribute name in code matches exactly with the attribute name in the file.

Comment: I typed it off the top of my head. That was just a typo. The actual code is correct. thanks though